# Isometric screen to map issue

Tags: c#, tiles, isometric

I know that about isometric map a lot of advice but I've read most of them and didn't solve my problem.
I rewrite code for C# for more simplicity (this code will be used on Android platform)
I need to get screen cords to isometric coords.

Here we go I used 1:2 tiles for me 64x32, I build diamond map using this code

```
private void drawIsoGrid(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    for(int y=0;y<20;y++)
        for(int x=0;x<20;x++)
        {
            float rx = (x - y) * (surface.Width) / 2 - globX;
            float ry = (x + y) * (surface.Height) / 2 - globY;
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(surface,rx,ry);
        }
```

I also use global anchor for scroll my map 
code here

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseCoordsX = e.X;
    mouseCoordsY = e.Y;
    if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        globX += prevX - e.X;
        globY += prevY - e.Y;
        this.Invalidate();
    }
    prevX = e.X;
    prevY = e.Y;            
}
```

the main question is how to get tile under the mouse which formula will be useful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this hasn't been answered, and it is one of the top results for "isometric screen" here, I figured I'd answer this (not to mention that I just finished this).

Since you have a function that maps from an iso grid to screen coordinates, and it's a linear transform with an inverse, we can just go backwards to get the other function.  So let's do just that.

We want to go from:

```
rx = (x - y) * (surface.Width) / 2 - globX
ry = (x + y) * (surface.Height) / 2 - globY
```

to:

```
x = <something>
y = <something>
```

It's easiest to solve these at the same time.  Add the globals to both sides:

```
rx + globX = (x - y) * (surface.Width) / 2
ry + globY = (x + y) * (surface.Height) / 2
```

Divide by `(surface.Width) / 2` and `(surface.Height) / 2`:

```
(rx + globX) / (surface.Width / 2)  = x - y
(ry + globY) / (surface.Height / 2) = x + y
```

Almost done, let's add both equations together to get rid of the `y`'s:

```
(rx + globX) / (surface.Width / 2) + (ry + globY) / (surface.Height / 2) = 2 * x
```

Now to get rid of the x's subtract the first equation from the second:

```
(ry + globY) / (surface.Height / 2) - (rx + globX) / (surface.Width / 2) = 2 * y
```

Divide both equations through by 2, and we're tentatively done:

```
x = ((rx + globX) / (surface.Width / 2) + (ry + globY) / (surface.Height / 2)) / 2
y = ((ry + globY) / (surface.Height / 2) - (rx + globX) / (surface.Width / 2)) / 2
```

Cool, now you have the grid coordinates in terms of the screen.  Let's clean some of this up, since we have basically `(a / (b / c)) / c` which is the same as `a / b`, we can get rid of the `c`'s, in this case the `2`'s:

```
x = (rx + globX) / surface.Width + (ry + globY) / surface.Height
y = (ry + globY) / surface.Height - (rx + globX) / surface.Width
```

So you should be able to write up a function that takes the screen x and y positions and returns the x and y grid positions.  I am not incredibly familiar with c# so I don't know how it handles float values that should be int's, but since you're running this on android, I suppose it doesn't really matter.